# Интеграция раздела «Вакансий»: появление вкладки «Работа» на Stack Overflow

Tags: обсуждение, объявления

> **TL;DR**:
>
> [image: Primary Navigation]
>
> Мы представляем вам новый раздел [Jobs on Stack Overflow («Работа на Stack Overflow»)](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs).
>   Благодарим всех, кто участвовал в тестировании на Meta Stack Overflow и сообщал об ошибках с меткой [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs) — так держать!
>
> <3

В 2009 году мы в Stack Overflow взяли на себя миссию по обеспечению программистов работой мечты. Мы [начали](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/jobs-at-stack-overflow/) с того, что включили в сеть сайт по трудоустройству Joel on Software. Затем мы [добавили раздел резюме](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/introducing-stack-overflow-careers/), для того чтобы вы смогли достойно презентовать ваши высочайшие умения и навыки, и [к вам стали обращаться работодатели](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/careers-now-open-for-businesses/). В 2011 мы [запустили Careers 2.0](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/careers-2-0-launches/) с бесплатным доступом для соискателей, с улучшенным форматом резюме и усовершенствованным поиском для работодателей. Раздел [Company Pages («Страницы компаний»)](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/08/finding-a-great-company/) появился в 2013 г., чтобы теперь уже работодатели могли представиться вам. В начале этого года был усовершенствован раздел [Job Ads («Объявления о трудоустройстве»)](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/targeted-jobs-for-stack-overflow/) — с помощью механизма более тщательного подбора вакансий с учетом данных пользователя. Мы фанатично преданы идее и мечтаем довести начатое до победного конца; для нас это отнюдь не побочный проект.

Но в связи с некоторыми довольно серьезными нюансами в работе пользовательского интерфейса мы не смогли представить программистам сервис на том уровне, который бы максимально соответствовал их потребностям, и который бы позволил полностью достичь наших целей по содействию в трудоустройстве программистов. [Тим довольно подробно обрисовал сложившуюся ситуацию](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310066/stack-overflow-serving-programmers-even-better):

> Многие из тех, кто читает данное сообщение, имеют великолепную и к тому же любимую работу. Но количество тех, кто ее не имеет, еще больше: при этом они не подозревают, что на Stack Overflow есть продукт, который мог бы помочь им в поиске лучшего места. Возможно, некоторые находили этот раздел, но потом теряли его, столкнувшись с необходимостью снова и снова регистрироваться и сообщать нам личные данные, которые (как они думали) они нам уже предоставляли.

Мы проделали огромную работу над разделом Careers («Вакансии») и он *работает*, но весь наш труд мы, фигурально выражаясь, спрятали в темном чулане дальней гостевой комнаты, закрыли в нее дверь и подперли столом, предварительно привязав к его ножке злую сторожевую собаку. Вам приходилось переходить на отдельный сайт и создавать отдельную учетную запись. Перед тем, как создать резюме, вам необходимо было правдами или неправдами раздобыть приглашение. Если вам не удавалось получить приглашение от друга или коллеги, вы просили его у нас, попадая в очередь, где один из сотрудников Stack Overflow в личном порядке рассматривал вашу заявку и собственноручно отправлял вам приглашение. **Одним словом, мы делали все возможное, чтобы усложнить вам жизнь.**

А вот данные, которые позволяют оценить пользу новой функциональности: согласно прошлогоднему исследованию, проводимому среди разработчиков Stack Overflow (2015 Stack Overflow Developer Survey), лишь один из трех респондентов заявил, что "любит свою работу".

[image: Job Satisfaction Question]

Кроме того, мы провели эксперимент: в течение года мы спрашивали пользователей, регистрирующихся на Stack Overflow, интересна ли им тема трудоустройства.

[image: Job Interest Field]

Около 60% людей заполнило это поле и около 60% от заполнивших указали, что находятся в активном поиске работы или открыты для предложений о трудоустройстве. **В целом, около 40% регистрирующихся на Stack Overflow в данный момент заинтересованы в поиске работы.**

Итак, ясно, что большой процент пользователей Stack Overflow нуждаются и заинтересованы в трудоустройстве, **поэтому мы просто должны перестать усложнять вам жизнь**. И лучший способ это сделать — перенести информацию об опыте кандидата из Careers непосредственно на вкладку Jobs, что мы и собираемся сделать. Никаких чуланов и злых собак, никаких дублирующихся учетных записей и сайтов, никакой мороки.

## Хотите попробовать?

Вкладка Jobs будет отныне доступна *всем и каждому*: [сходите и убедитесь](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs). Если вы обнаружите ошибку, пожалуйста, разместите соответствующее сообщение на Meta Stack Overflow с меткой [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs). Мы уже некоторое время работали над созданием доски объявлений, которая помогала бы вам произвести хорошее впечатление на работодателя, но теперь, с вашей помощью, дело пойдет еще быстрее.

## FAQ

#### Какие изменения произойдут на Stack Overflow?

[image: Primary Navigation]

Вот, примерно, и все, что поменяется на Stack Overflow с вводом новой функциональности. В том, что касается вопросов и ответов, не изменится ничего. Мы не собираемся маскировать вакансии под вопросы, публиковать их в виде ответов или же использовать другие подобные схемы. Вкладка Jobs будет ждать своего часа, пока она вам не понадобится — а суть Stack Overflow остается неизменной.

#### Что будет на вкладке Jobs («Работа»)?

В целом, все то же, что вы привыкли видеть на Careers…

[image: Jobs Tab]

Вы сможете осуществлять поиск по вакансиям и компаниям-работодателям, создавать и редактировать свое резюме, а также читать свои сообщения прямо на странице.

#### Что будет с моей текущей информацией в Careers («Вакансии»)?

Если ранее вы связали свое резюме из раздела Careers с учетной записью на Stack Overflow, все, что находится на вкладке Jobs («Работа»), должно работать.

#### Теперь вы покажете мое конфиденциальное резюме всему миру?

**НЕТ.** Ваша конфиденциальность превыше всего.

#### А что насчет API и выгрузок баз данных?

Без изменений. Данные Jobs и CV не входят ни в Stack Exchange API, ни в публичные выгрузки.

#### Что будет с моей публичной ссылкой на резюме?

Публичные ссылки на ваше резюме (такие как [эта](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jasonpunyon)) остаются рабочими, но будут вести на `https://stackoverflow.com/cv/{ваше-имя}`

#### Почему кнопка Apply («Откликнуться») на Stack Overflow выглядит иначе?

Если вам приходилось пользоваться кнопкой Apply ранее, я бы хотел лично перед вами извиниться. Ее работа была настолько непонятной и неправильной, что нам не может быть оправдания. Позор на наши седины. С этой кнопкой все было настолько плохо, что мы просто все переделали и переписали.

---

Это свободный перевод публикации: «[Careers Unificintegration: Jobs on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/)». Раздела «Jobs» пока что не будет на Stack Overflow на русском. Он появится, как только основная часть дефектов будет устранена.

Comment: Как всегда: это очень здорово и это не на Stack Overflow на русском )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, тем не менее боковой виджет от Careers.SO таргетирует мне российские вакансии.

Comment: А вам не кажется, что если 40% пользователей ищет работу, то либо поиск работы у сайта работает хреново и тогда никто из ищущих не будет им пользоваться, либо они настолько плохи, что не могут найти работу и никто из работодателей не будет этим пользоваться. PS. целых 7 вакансий в России!

Comment: @Vartlok а вакансии за рубежом вы вообще не рассматриваете?

Comment: @NickVolynkin рассматривать могу, претендовать не могу)

Comment: В каком виде этот раздел появится у нас? В смысле, если вакансии будут только из России, то оратор выше подчеркнул заинтересованность местных компаний. Если будут международные, то раздел, наверное, не будет локализован, а тогда зачем он нам?

Comment: З.Ы. Когда  увидел, что вопрос отредактировал alexander barakin, первое, что пришло в голову было "удалил приветствие, наверное" :D

Comment: @LEQADA, и в первом комментарии будет написано "придерживайтесь, пожалуйста, принятой практики" )