# Разрешите представить: «История разработчика»

Tags: обсуждение, объявления

> ### TL;DR;
>
> Мы меняем CV (резюме) на учётную запись нового формата, которую можно использовать, даже если в данный момент вы не ищете работу.

В последнее время мы анонсировали множество изменений на Stack Overflow, включая обновление [документации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1247/), публикацию материала [«Власть командам»](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow), и наш план [по лучшему обслуживанию программистов](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310066/stack-overflow-serving-programmers-even-better) путем создания единого ресурса для сбора [вакансий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2335/).

[image: we're back]

Мы начали с [обновления профиля](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309870/new-expanded-profile-information), чтобы вы имели возможность подробнее рассказать о себе. Но мы пошли и дальше: впереди реализация обновления, которое, как мы думаем, будет называться **Developer Story** («История разработчика»).

### Что представляет собой История разработчика?

Спасибо за вопрос! «История разработчика» — это наше представление о том, как лучше показать все грани вашей личности как разработчика программного обеспечения. Скорее всего, выглядеть это будет следующим образом:

> [image: Developer story mockup]

### Для кого предназначена История разработчика?

Stack Overflow — это место, куда приходят разработчики, чтобы делиться знаниями — а как результат, создавать себе репутацию в зависимости от ценности вклада в базу знаний сообщества. Кроме того, это место, где вы можете поучаствовать в написании Документации (Documentation), вступить в Команду (Team), и даже заняться поиском работы. Теперь, с новой Историей разработчика, **у вас есть возможность рассказать, кем вы являетесь и над чем работаете,** и эта возможность доступна каждому, независимо от того, для каких целей вы используете сайт.

[image: everybody gets one]

Эту функциональность задумывалась для того, чтобы разработчикам было удобнее делиться информацией о завершенных проектах (независимо от того, интересует ли их вопрос трудоустройства). Известно, что около 40% зарегистрированных на сайте разработчиков заинтересованы в получении информации об открытых вакансиях, а остальным новая функциональность даст прекрасную возможность произвести впечатление на собратьев по цеху.

- Если вы ищете достойную работу: История разработчика является обновлением Careers CV. В новом формате упор сделан на завершенных проектах и используемых технологиях; малополезная информация, содержавшаяся в традиционном резюме, отсутствует.
- Вы уже нашли работу мечты? Поделитесь достижениями: ещё недавно такой возможности не существовало. Ваша история — это **ваш** путь программиста.

Даже если вы просто используете сайт как справочник или создали профиль Stack Overflow для демонстрации его потенциальным работодателям, в «Истории разработчика» вы сможете показать всему миру, насколько вы успешны как программист.

### У нас уже есть учётная запись участника, зачем нам ещё и История разработчика?

[Учётная запись](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226177/the-profile-page-is-getting-a-makeover-part-one) никуда не денется. Она создаётся для каждого участника после регистрации на Stack Overflow; в ней содержится ваша биография и ваши метки; по желанию, вы можете указать в нём свою должность и место работы. Учётные записи заполнены у многих участников, но **заполненная учёная запись не даёт полного представления о вашей личности, и мы пытаемся это исправить.**

Формат Истории разработчика позволяет пойти намного дальше — вы можете более подробно описать свой опыт в качестве разработчика программного обеспечения. Мы бы хотели, чтобы разработчики могли сами рассказать о себе, уделяя внимание следующим основным моментам:

- Текущая и предыдущие должности и места работы.
- Используемые технологии и метки, в которых вы принимаете участие на Stack Overflow.
- Проект с открытым исходным кодом, книги или блоги, авторами которых вы являетесь

Когда разработчики говорят о своих проектах, они упоминают, что разрабатывают в какой-то среде и с помощью тех или иных технологий. Ответы на эти вопросы не входят в тот профиль, который мы имеем сейчас, но они очень важны. Предлагаемый новый формат учётной записи дает более полную картину того, кем вы являетесь и чего достигли. Учебное заведение, которое вы посещаете или окончили, ваши действия на GitHub, ваши проекты или приложения с открытым кодом: вы сможете собрать всё, что сделали или над чем работаете в одном месте — и показать это другим.

Бóльшая часть вашей «Истории» будет видна всем, кто будет её просматривать. Но если вы хотите, чтобы ваше участие в работе Stack Overflow и процесс поиска работы не пересекались, не беспокойтесь: настройки конфиденциальности Истории разработчика позволят вам контролировать, кто и что сможет просматривать.

### FAQ

**Какую проблему это решает?**

- Вы получаете возможность заявить о ваших умениях и навыках, а также шанс найти работу вашей мечты.
- Новый формат пришел на смену существующему CV (резюме), с традиционной, но не всегда оптимальной структурой; Историю разработчика можно использовать, даже если вы не ищете работу.
- История разработчика фокусируется на том, что ценят программисты и работодатели, а именно — на истории завершенных проектов, а не на простом перечислении мест работы и учебы.

**Что произойдёт с существующими CV (резюме), перенесёнными с Careers?**

История разработчика была задумана как замена резюме. В дальнейшем мы более подробно остановимся на этом вопросе, но на данный момент все существующие резюме будут перенесены в новую систему с сохранением настроек конфиденциальности: если у вас был закрытый профиль, ваша История также будет закрыта.

**Похоже, Stack Overflow становится социальной сетью?**

Это не так. Здесь не будет «друзей», «подписок» и других способов установления социальных связей, кроме как неявно, через общего работодателя. История разработчика — это просто расширение учётной записи.

**Как быть, если я хочу ограничить публичный доступ к своей Истории?**

Это не проблема: аналогично настройкам конфиденциальности CV, вы сможете полностью ограничить доступ к Истории разработчика, либо скрыть её на сайте, но с возможностью поиска работодателями.

**А что, если мне не нужна «История разработчика»?**

Если вы не хотите делиться подробностями своей трудовой биографии, никто не вправе заставить вас это сделать. Заполнение Истории — дело добровольное.

**Сохранится ли возможность экспорта в PDF?**

Да, эта возможность остаётся.

**Как новая функциональность повлияет на мою работу на других сайтах Stack Exchange?**

История разработчика пока будет существовать только на Stack Overflow, но она позволит вам размещать ссылки на ваши лучшие ответы на других сайтах Stack Exchange.

### Что дальше?

Мы надеемся, нам удалось найти наилучший способ представления информации о вашем опыте и выполненных проектах, но **мы все равно нуждаемся в вашей помощи: всё ли мы учли, не упускаем ли из виду чего-либо важного?**

- Какие еще сведения вы хотели бы сообщить о себе как о разработчике программного обеспечения? Сообществу? Работодателям?
- Чем из ваших достижений вы хотели бы поделиться?

Обновление произойдет через 6-8 недель, а пока будем ждать ваших ответов!

---

Свободный перевод статьи «[Introducing the Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313960/)». История разработчика станет доступной на Stack Overflow на русском, как только будут исправлены критические дефекты новой функциональности.

Обратите внимание, есть вторая часть: «[История разработчика, часть 2](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2400/)».

Comment: А где это должно появиться? или когда? пока что-то не вижу такого пункта

Comment: @Grundy, это пока Work In Progress

Comment: @Nofate, ага, Николас уже ответил в чате, что месяц-два и на английском может появиться

Comment: Сегодня они говорят, что не превращаются в соцсеть, а завтра...

Comment: Ха-ха-ха, оценка поста на МСО ещё круче, чем у Документации. :D

Comment: ...и завтра Stack Overflow останется Stack Overflow.