# Каково иметь большую репутацию?

Tags: обсуждение, репутация

Очевидно, что репутация отражает вклад и опыт участника. Интересно, становится ли репутация, со временем, фактором, который "меняет/корректирует" отношение к себе, к людям?

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Уточните, что вы хотите видеть в ответе?

Comment: Мнение хотелось бы услышать участников с большим рейтингом, ваше, например. По моему вполне конкретный вопрос. Незнаю как его еще конкретизировать.

Comment: @TimurVI Уточните хотя бы что значит "большой" рейтинг? С какого значения надо считать его большим?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov в том то и дело, что уточнение моё будет моим субъективным мнением о том, когда рейтинг начинает становиться фактором. У кого-то и в 100К может не быть никакой рефлексии на рейтинг, а на ком-то после 1К начинает сказываться (возможно). Честно, ну как тут его обозначить. Тогда вопрос можно удалить.

Comment: Небольшая поправка: то, о чём вы спрашиваете, назвается *репутация* участника. Рейтинг есть, например, у вопросов — это количество голосов за минус количество голосов против.

Comment: @NickVolynkin согласен с вами, спасибо

Comment: @NickVolynkin Репутация - ничто. Ромб - все!

Comment: К сожалению, да. Стараюсь не поддаваться, контролировать себя (и уже это, собственно, становится корректирующим фактором (такая вот рекурсия в стиле [GNU](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU) -)))

Comment: @PashaPash  ага, я как ромб получил, перестал беспокоиться о репутации. )

Answer (score 19):

Психологи говорят, что типичному человеку комфортно состоять в социальных группах, в которых его репутация находится выше среднего уровня.

На stackoverflow большинство посетителей сайта оставляет один вопрос и больше никогда на сайт не заходит. Поэтому любая репутация выше 100 баллов – это уже выше среднего уровня.

Я по этому поводу люблю цитировать пассаж из моего любимого "Графа Монте-Кристо":

> Монте-Кристо остановился перед щитом и внимательно осмотрел его.
>      - По лазоревому полю семь  золотых  мерлеток,  расположенных  снопом. Это, конечно, ваш фамильный герб, виконт? - спросил он. - Если
>   не  считать того, что я знаком с геральдическими  фигурами  и 
>   поэтому  кое-как разбираюсь в гербах, я плохой знаток геральдики; ведь
>   я граф  случайный, сфабрикованный в Тоскане за учреждение командорства
>   святого Стефана,  и, пожалуй, не принял бы титула, если бы мне не
>   твердили, что, когда  много путешествуешь, это совершенно необходимо.
>   Надо же  иметь  что-нибудь  на дверцах кареты, хотя бы для того, чтобы
>   таможенные чиновники вас не  осматривали

Собственно, есть некоторые неудобства, когда ты жмёшь какую-то кнопку – а тебя система не пускает, говорит, что мало у тебя репутации для использования этих инструментов.

Например, когда ты хочешь сделать какую-то мелкую правку – а тебя заставляют "нужно поменять минимум 6 символов в тексте" (а если их там нету – что их, выдумывать?) или твои правки должны пройти модерацию (некоторые новички вообще не любят ждать, когда утвердят правку их же собственных текстов – жгут прямо в поле "ответ", туда же и комментарии вливают).

Для себя я определил комфортный уровень как 2500 - 3500 репутации, тут примерно и нахожусь, резко выше не вижу никакого смысла рвать жилы. Тысячу репутации я когда-то давно ещё набрал за неделю активного сидения на сайте (пока был в отпуске, скучно было) и поэтому знаю, что набрать любой рейтинг – не просто реально, а можно быстро это сделать. Так, капает помаленьку... Могу даже привести конкретные примеры людей, кто набрал больше меня репутацию при этом на сайт пришёл много позже меня. В этом смысле репутация – лишь отражение вклада в человека в сообщество, сколько он времени потратил (прямая пропорциональность).

Репутация также – это один из инструментов, которые ускоряют процесс опознавания людей в иерархии. Несмотря на то, что в ИТ-сообществе обычно больше полагаются на собственое личное мнение – эти механизмы также работают. Вместо того, чтобы долго вычитывать все ответы какого-то пользователя – вам достаточно мельком глянуть на его набор плашек (10к репы... ага, три года на сайте... золото по c#) и всё становится понятно с высокой точностью за очень короткое время. Как правило, это работает в плюс, хотя вот [только недавно](/a/4363/213987) @PashaPash упрекал, что поддались стадному инстинкту и повелись на репутацию. (Кстати, зряшный упрёк: и я сам вчитывался и других знаю, кто читал)

Я для себя выделяю на сайте три группы: с высокой репутацией (условно – от 7к - 10к), средней – (где-то в районе 2к - 5к) и низкой (менее 300). У каждой группы свои паттерны поведения, это в общем-то наглядно видно.

И как правило, человек очень быстро занимает на сайте то место, которое он занимает в реальной жизни. Ещё вчера у него была единичка в профиле, потом хороший ответ, другой – а через полгода у него уже за 2к репутации. И паттерн такой характерный: ни одного вопроса на сайте не задал, а в профиле – вся грудь в орденах.

Каково оно быть с большой репутацией? Точнее – с той репутацией, которой ты достиг? (перечитываем первое предложение поста) Да никак особо. Ты просто чувствуешь себя на своём месте. Если репутация честно заработана, а не нафармлена – то ты чувствуешь это не только "изнутри" (самооценка), но и получаешь обратную связь от социума ("да, ты такой и есть") и уважительное отношение.

Задумываются о репутации все участники, это свойственно всем людям. Просто – в разной степени. 
Особой фиксации на этом вопросе нет среди тех, кто набрал сверхвысокий рейтинг. Тут, понимаете какая штука. Высокий рейтинг получают не те, кто хочет получить большой рейтинг – а те, кто не гонится за высоким рейтингом. (К слову: [Зачем вы здесь?](/q/305/213987))  Это звучит странно, может покажется спорным – но тем не менее. Кстати и HR'ы говорят, что больше зарплата не у тех, кто целенаправленно идёт за большим рублём – а у тех, кто любит своё дело, свою работу. Говорю как человек несколько лет проработавший в кадровом агентстве.
Как раз чуть больше фиксация на рейтинге среди тех, кто ещё не довёл свой рейтинг до уровня, отражающий реальные возможности. Но как только набирается – уже об этом практически не думают.

Это всё разумеется при "прочих равных" и "в среднем по больнице", я не хочу ввязываться в споры из серии "а бывает и иначе".

Самые крупные исключения – это постоянное "кармофермерство", когда у человека с заниженной самооценкой включаются компенсационные механизмы.

Как-то так в двух словах. Не знаю, отвечает ли это на ваши вопросы. Если прочитав захочется что-то уточнить подробнее – спрашивайте в комментариях.

Comment: а чем отличается "честно заработал" и "нафармил"?

Comment: @pavel Я вам отвечу вольным определением невроза: "невроз -- это когда человек тратит на какое-то действие намного больше психической энергии, чем люди обычно". Нафармил -- это когда слишком сильно акцентируешься на вопросе, а уж если это происходит не эпизодически, а постоянно... Честно заработал -- это в данном контексте означает "особо не заморачиваясь этими рейтингами". В том, что фермерство -- это ударный стахановский труд и что оно требует и ума, и силы воли и трудолюбия -- я нисколько не ставлю под сомнение. Фермерство тоже в чём-то заслуживает уважения.

Comment: @pavel целью. При фарме репутации конечная цель это очки репутации, контент вторичен. С "честно заработал", собственно, наоборот. Снаружи (а порой и изнутри) сложно судить, что из двух имеет место.

Comment: [Медиана репутации на Stack Overflow равна **единице**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296967/4279)

Answer (score 12):

Объективно: при росте репутации постепенно открываются [новые привилегии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), они открывают некоторые дополнительные возможности и позволяют участвовать в модерации сайта.

Субъективно для других: да, наверняка большое число рядом с именем производит некоторое впечатление. Однако репутация никогда не является аргументом в споре «какое решение лучше». Периодически бывает, что великолепный ответ даётся участником с единичкой репутации.

Субъективно для себя: репутация, рейтинги по меткам и знаки — это часть геймификации сайта. Лично от вас зависит, насколько это вас мотивирует: от полного безразличия до [реальности в два потока](http://ithappens.me/story/12066).

При трудоустройстве: по моему небольшому опыту, репутация не очень важна при поиске работы. Работодателя скорее впечатлит высокий рейтинг по конкретной метке. (Меня как-то раз эйчары просили сделать выборку из [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) по городу и метке.) Можно также похвастаться конкретными ответами, в том числе добавить их в свою [Историю разработчика (Developer story)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2399/181472).

Смотрите также: [Как работает репутация?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3663/181472)

Comment: Уточните плиз, что такое SEDE?

Comment: @Kromster Stack Exchange Data Explorer, https://data.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 10):

#### Больше всего репутации приносит не решение *сложной* проблемы, а решение *часто возникающей*

Так что показатель репутации я рассматриваю скорее как **искусственный ограничительный фактор для выдачи привилегий**, работающий за счёт приблизительного соответствия "степени освоения принципов работы сообщества". То есть, рассматриваю её исключительно с технической точки зрения и не вижу в ней значительного достижения или показателя каких-то исключительных качеств и навыков. Это касается отношения как к себе, так и к другим.

Достигнув 10к, я получил интересовавшие меня инструменты. Да, какое-то время в душе царила радость достижения и руки прямо-таки чесались попробовать новые привилегии в деле. Я попробовал, быстро остыл.

Я понимаю, что его **можно** связывать с технической грамотностью в определённых областях, но чтобы её оценить, одного показателя репутации, на мой взгляд, недостаточно. Интересующемуся лучше сходить и посмотреть на сами ответы.

---

Это, впрочем, не означает, что я свернул свою активность на StackOverflow. Просто большое число в репутации для меня не является мотивом. Тем более, что число я оцениваю скорее логарифмически, и на моём уровне репутации сколько-нибудь резкие изменения уже не происходят.

Плюсы приятны примерно как сказанное в быту "спасибо", минусы тоже воспринимаю спокойно, интересуюсь, в чём беда. Не отвечают — ну и ладно. Как правило, я ручаюсь за правильность ответов, которые публикую (и указываю явно, если нет) и не нуждаюсь в дополнительных подтверждениях того, что я эксперт в некоторой области, через какие-то абстрактные числа. Мои ответы говорят сами за себя.

Answer (score 1):

1) По достижению несколько десятков тысяч репутации вас могут сделать модераторами сообщества, чтобы вы имели большую власть на сайте.

2) В SO всё работает так, что если пользователь удаляется с сайта, то все его голоса также удаляются, а репутация аннулируется. Но если у вас много репы, то ваши голоса не удалятся.

3) Репутация также сделана для морального удовлетворения :)

Comment: Не нужно иметь много репутации, чтобы баллотироваться в модераторы. См. блок справа на [страничке выборов 2019](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/3?tab=nomination).

Comment: А сколько нужно, @αλεχολυτ?

Comment: Аааа, всего лишь 300? Я думал, где-то хотя бы от тысяч 2-х или 3-х