# Абсурдная логика лайка

Tags: обсуждение

Уже не первый раз встречаю, что когда ты даёшь кратки ответ на самый лёгкий вопрос, то за 10 минут можно получить 100500 лайков. При том, когда ты отвечаешь на сложный вопрос хорошим ответом, то за день вряд ли сможешь и 5 лайков набрать.

*Как пример:*
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/688511/20458
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/688567/20458

Кто знает, почему так? Зачем давать сложный ответы, если можно ответить на самые простые и получить больше репутации, тем самым больше и больше мотивироваться решать только такие вопросы?

Comment: Потому, что большинству лень читать *много букв* (короче, "краткость сестра таланта")

Comment: Лайк головного мозга... Тут нет лайков

Comment: Ты тут репы наваривать пришел или людям помогать? Если людям помогать - то зачем ныть? Если репы наварить - то что за недовольство?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, если ты помогаешь людям (нормальным), то получаешь шиш. Это и напрягает

Comment: @Yuri Никто никого не заставляет что-то делать. Дело добровольное. Если тебя не устраивает, что мало репы за твои труды, значит ты пришел не помогать, а за наградками гнаться. Таким "помощникам" грош цена

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, твои диалоги похожи на зарплаты в России :) "Врачи: спасать жизнь, это добровольное дело. ВЫ можете уволиться. Если вы помогаете людям ради денег - грош вам цена"

Comment: [**Kit Scribe**: fun это хорошо, но я не веселюсь, отвечая на вопросы. Моей мотивацией была репутация.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36794281#36794281) ..........[**avp**: *репутация* это и есть ваша трагическая ошибка.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36794396#36794396)

Comment: Связанное: [Каково иметь большую репутацию?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4426/181100)

Comment: @Yuri всё так. я бы лично не хотел попасться к врачу, который изначально не  радеет за человеческие жизни, а цель - разжиться баблом.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, особенно у него есть 2k в месяц за спасение жизни, а у тебя 50k за подписание бумажек (это метафора)

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5581/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0#comment21206_5581 ......... ты уж определись: либо ты альтруист, либо лицемер

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Хороший вопрос != частый вопрос.**

Большая часть, посетителей русскоязычного сообщества это новички в программирование, которые ищут и задают относительно лёгкие вопросы. Соответственно, частота показа их выше чем у сложных вопросов. И, как результат, "лайков" больше. Так же играет роль лаконичность ответа.

Общая репутация на RU SO -  в большей мере отражает Ваш вклад в сообщество, а не отдельные познания в какой-нибудь области.

Скажем так, можно ответить на кучу простых вопросов и заработать огромную репутацию, но это не будет отражать Ваши познания в данной области. Поэтому, конечно надо отвечать на сложные вопросы, потому что они отражают Ваши знания. И тот момент, что ответ набрал мало "лайков" (но всё таки набрал), говорит о том, что, скорее всего, этот сложный ответ был полезен не только новичкам.

И, самое главное, оставляя ответ, не важно сколько он набрал "лайков".  Ваш вклад в сообщество уже имеется. Потому, что цель сообщества - это помощь. И если вдруг Вы окажетесь в ситуации, в которой уже Вам нужна будет помощь, то согласитесь, будет приятно, что люди здесь помогают просто так, без корысти, и не посмотрят, что вопрос сложный и не стоит отвечать на него потому что мало лайков поставят.

Comment: Было бы приятно... но на мои сложные вопросы в основном отвечают, когда я ставлю награду не меньше чем в 200 единиц репутации

Comment: @Yuri тут конечно несколько причин. Во-первых не знание ответа, а за 200 ед можно и посидеть разобраться. Во-вторых, вопросов с наградами обычно до 20 их хоть каждый день можно просматривать, а обычный вопрос с первой страницы уйдёт за час - два.

Comment: "за 200 посидеть и разобраться"... кто-то про честь говорил там (комменты в вопросе). Жалко что нельзя и за просто так подумать

Comment: @Yuri многие просто забывают, что цель сообщества - это бескорыстная помощь. С другой стороны, написав хороший ответ, даже если он ничего не получил, Вы растёте в своих глазах, заставляете уважать себя других участников сообщества. Даже для себя это полезно просто перечитать по необходимости.

Comment: Это уж точно. Один раз написал ответ с вычислением, так до сих пор не пойму откуда взял числа

Comment: тоже такая ситуация была :)