# Какой смысл заработка репутации на подобных форумах опытным программистам, которые только отвечают на вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение

Какой смысл заработка репутации на подобных форумах опытным программистам, которые только отвечают на вопросы?

Comment: вопрос ещё раз перечитай

Comment: Советую почитать [ответ @AK](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4382/208074) на вопрос «Каково иметь большую репутацию?» Там как раз описана мотивация её зарабатывания.