# История разработчика, часть 2

Tags: обсуждение, объявления

Не так давно мы анонсировали идею [«Истории разработчика»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2399/), чтобы выслушать ваши комментарии и получить обратную связь — и мы ее получили! Спасибо за все комментарии и ответы в теме.

Задним умом мы понимаем, что всё упустили, [не последовав нашему собственному совету](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta/272617#272617), и не предоставив всех подробностей о новой функциональности; в данном сообщении мы постараемся восполнить провал. Проще говоря,

[image: part 2]

---

*(Мы облажались! Но сиквел лучше оригинала!!)*

**История разработчика — это эволюция традиционного резюме (CV); этот формат призван заменить резюме из раздела Jobs (или Careers) («Работа» или «Вакансии»).** Это не новый функционал — это часть проекта по [интеграции доски объявлений о работе в Stack Overflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2335/), цель которой — усовершенствование существующей функциональности. История разработчика предоставит участникам возможность демонстрации собственных возможностей в новом формате. История разработчика поможет вам найти работу. Если же поиск работы вас не интересует, вы можете полностью проигнорировать данное обновление: на основной функционал сайта, вопросы и ответы, она не повлияет.

### Какую проблему мы пытаемся решить?

Резюме как явление существует уже более 500 лет: его изобрели [для того, чтобы достойным образом представлять странствующих лордов](http://www.lettersofnote.com/2012/03/skills-of-da-vinci.html). Использование резюме в качестве визитной карточки имеет смысл, если вам нужно продемонстрировать свой послужной список, но ведь каждый человек — это не просто совокупность регалий и мест работы. Помимо этого, вы — это то, **над чем вы работаете и что уже завершили**. Технология уходит вперед, а резюме технических специалистов не меняются, поэтому мы решили пересмотреть способ подачи информации в профессиональной деятельности.

При запуске Stack Overflow наше сообщество заняло довольно решительную позицию: *судить нужно по тому, что ты знаешь, а не тому, кто ты есть*. Иначе говоря, оценивать надо содержимое, а не личность автора. Мы твердо уверены, что и к найму разработчиков лучше подходить именно с этих позиций. **История разработчика — это ваша история:** вам предоставляется более удачный способ поиска любимой работы на основании того, **что вы умеете делать**, а не того, кем вы являетесь. Вместо того чтобы презентовать себя в виде списка растиражированных клише, вы сможете разместить в вашей Истории только то, что для вас действительно важно, включая перечень технологий, над которыми вы работали и разрабатываемые вами проекты с открытым исходным кодом.

Дизайн Истории разработчика отличается от дизайна традиционного резюме: мы пытаемся повлиять на мышление работодателей, заставив их уделять больше внимания вашим реальным достижениям. Понимая, что переходный процесс займет какое-то время, мы оставляем за работодателями право просматривать ваш послужной список в традиционном виде, но даже в этом представлении работодатель увидит более полную картину вашего профессионального пути.

### Новый раздел называется История разработчика, но я не разработчик; я смогу использовать эту функциональность?

Мы испытываем [определенные трудности с разработкой новой терминологии](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306346/naming-the-documentation-feature), потому что **изобретение названий — дело непростое.**  Мы выбрали именно это название, и как нам кажется, им можно адресовать [большую часть участников Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#work-occupation). Но если у вас есть соображения, каким образом назвать этот раздел, мы с радостью их рассмотрим.

Даже если по профессиональному классификатору вас нельзя назвать разработчиком, у нас найдутся предложения работы как для программистов, так и для системных администраторов и менеджеров проектов; этот функционал доступен всем участникам Stack Overflow независимо от названия их должности. В данный момент нецелесообразно запускать сразу несколько сайтов по трудоустройству, и, учитывая, что большинство участников — разработчики программного обеспечения, логично было бы разместить подобный раздел именно на Stack Overflow. Работодатели, тем не менее, могут производить сортировку по любой профессии, поэтому, если вы опубликовали свои данные и заинтересованы в работе, вас найдут.

### Почему я не могу поделиться информацией с других сайтов, входящих в Stack Exchange?

Это не так! Вы уже сейчас можете добавлять ответы с высоким рейтингом с других сайтов Stack Exchange, и мы ищем способы расширить этот функционал.

### Как быть, если я не хочу размещать данные о моей работе и карьере на Stack Overflow?

Интеграция доски объявлений о трудоустройстве в Stack Overflow означает, что у нас больше не будет двух систем с изолированными данными. Все существующие резюме мы переместим в новый раздел История разработчика, соблюдая при этом настройки конфиденциальности. Конфиденциальность имеет для нас огромное значение, поэтому если в данный момент ваши данные защищены от просмотра, они останутся таковыми и в новой версии. Вы также сможете, если захотите, полностью скрыть вашу Историю, либо сделать её видимой только для работодателей.

### Stack Overflow становится сайтом по трудоустройству?

Stack Overflow — дом для разработчиков всего мира. Мы стремимся к тому, чтобы стать местом, где бы вы находили решение большенства ваших проблем. Мы начали с того, что создали лучший сайт вопросов и ответов, и в данный момент расширяем спектр услуг, предоставляемых разработчикам, 
[улучшая документацию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1247/) и совершенствуя процесс поиска работы, чтобы каждый программист смог найти работу своей мечты.

Поэтому ответ на этот вопрос отрицательный: превращать Stack Overflow ни в сайт по трудоустройству, ни в сайт для хранения документации мы отнюдь не собираемся. Вопросы и ответы всегда были и остаются нашим ключевым продуктом, как и [говорил Тим](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310066/stack-overflow-serving-programmers-even-better):

> Ничто не заставит нас отойти от нашего основного направления — вопросов и ответов. То, что мы создали с вами вместе, всегда будет в центре внимания, без вариантов.

Но хотя вопросы и ответы всегда будут иметь приоритет в нашей работе, это больше не **единственный** функционал Stack Overflow. И все же, сколько бы новых элементов мы ни вводили, какую бы функциональность ни добавляли, раздел вопросов и ответов будет на сайте всегда.

### Stack Overflow превращается в социальную сеть?

История разработчика — актуальный список ваших умений и навыков. Любое сходство с другими ресурсами просим считать случайным совпадением.

Мы бы так с вами не поступили. Равно как и с проектом.

### Мы превратились в проект, ориентированный на инвесторов?

Нет, мы по-прежнему ориентированы на продукт. По факту, мы исторически воспринимали сайт вопросов и ответов исключительно как продукт — до такой степени, что участники могли легко забыть, что мы являемся бизнесом, который должен приносить прибыль. Чтобы продолжать расти и развиваться, мы обязаны искать новые уникальные пути соответствия интересам разработчиков, либо выходить на более высокий уровень обслуживания — в случае уже существующих на рынке услуг. Наши инвесторы ожидают от нас непрерывного роста, но они отнюдь не диктуют нам, какие шаги мы должны для этого предпринять.

**Наш рост ни в коем случае не означает отказа следовать нашей миссии по предоставлению лучшего в мире места для вопросов и ответов по программированию,** но мы понимаем опасения, которые высказали многие из вас. Уже очень долгое время мы занимались только форматом «вопрос-ответ», и приобрели известность именно в этом контексте. Но сейчас мы говорим о целом ряде нововведений, довольно далеких от нашего основного продукта. При этом мы не очень подробно рассказываем о работе над ним, [хотя работа эта не прекращается](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/01/year-in-review-2015/).

Мы услышали вас: мы будет предоставлять вам больше информации о том, над чем работаем в рамках сервиса вопросов и ответов. Теперь, когда у нас имеется более одного сервиса, мы больше не будем предполагать, что все по умолчанию знают о том, что мы делаем. Просим прощения за то, что взяли на себя смелость делать такие предположения.

Да, нам нужно поработать над реализацией потенциала раздела вакансий, что порадует наших инвесторов. Но основная цель, которая стоит и всегда будет стоять за любыми нашими действиями — отстаивание интересов разработчиков в той степени, которая позволит поддерживать функционирование нашего совместного детища на достойном уровне.

### Подводя итог, что все это значит?

Наша платформа экспертных вопросов и ответов — это то, на чем основан весь проект; она никогда не потеряет для нас первостепенной важности, не говоря уже о том, чтобы мы какими-то своими действиями препятствовали её развитию. С вашей помощью мы изменили формат вопросов и ответов: надеемся, в лучшую сторону. А теперь мы ищем способы решения некоторых других довольно важных проблем разработчиков, с той же обстоятельностью и эффективностью, с какой работали над разделом вопросов и ответов.

Мы всегда будем рады выслушать ваше мнение. Мы искренне ценим все то время, которое каждый из вас уделяет улучшениям и исправлениям на сайте. Мы просим прощения за то, что изначально не дали более подробных комментариев. И еще раз напоминаем: вы не обязаны использовать Историю разработччика, если вы этого не хотите — ничего против мы не имеем.

---

Это свободный перевод статьи «[The Developer Story Part 2: We didn't explain that very well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/)».

Comment: Это ведь тоже [важное]?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Не хотел перегружать боковую панель (добавил ссылку в первую публикацию).

Comment: да нормально, не выглядит перегруженной.

Comment: Исправьте **функционал** в соответствии с его значением, которое не имеет отношения к данной статье.

Comment: @approximatenumber Пожалуйста, поясните, что именно вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky [Значение слова](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB), а остальное - не очень опрятный жаргонизм около-IT индустрии. Возможно, на менее серьезном портале это слово и могло бы иметь место, но не здесь, наверное. Просто пишите **функциональность** (или синонимы) ;-)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky есть ли шанс, что история разработчика или подобный функционал когда-нибудь всё-таки появится в русском SO? Уверен, возможность привлечения работодателей стала бы мощным стимулом для отвечающих.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Шанс есть, но когда именно это произойдет сказать не берусь.

Answer (score 4):

Всё понял и идея нравится ... НО:
Почему закладка Jobs отображается только на stackoverflow.com?
Я чаще захожу именно на https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/ и та же закладка именно здесь была бы уместнее и удобнее, во всяком случае для русской аудитории.
Спасибо.

Comment: см. [первую часть вопроса](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2399/5079): *История разработчика станет доступной на Stack Overflow на русском, как только будут исправлены критические дефекты новой функциональности*

Comment: Упс :) ... значит пропустил. Спасибо, порадовали :)

Comment: Полгода прошло, а функционала всё ещё нет :(

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev F

Comment: @Suvitruf F?​​‌‌‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌​​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Press_F_to_Pay_Respects.jpg